# Java - base url after 302 redirect

Tags: java, apache, http, url, http-status-code-302

I've came up with the following problem. In my application I need to post an XML file to a server and wait for it's reply. I've achieved the above by using Apache HttpClient:

- create the xml
- using HttpClient and Post to post it to the server

The server initially responded with a 302 (Object moved), so I used LaxRedirectStrategy to be able to follow the redirect. I wrap the response in a StringBuffer and then push it into a new tab of the browser. Everything works fine, the tab shows the complete response from that server but every action in that page is not associated to the URL of the server response but to my main application. So, for example, if my application is on https://myapplication.com and the server is on https://theotherserver.com (+ /redirect for the redirect), each action on the page (i.e. /action) leads to https://myapplication.com/action and not to https://theotherserver.com/action.

In my page I have a button where this process starts. When you click it, it executes:

```
   jQuery('input#button').on
            (
                'click',
                function ()
                {
                    jQuery.ajax
                    (
                        {
                            url: 'myURL.do',
                            data: {data: mydata},
                            method: 'POST',
                            success: function(data)
                            {
                                if (data.success == 'true')
                                {
                                    var w = window.open('tab', windowname');
                                    w.document.write(data.result);
                                    w.document.close();
                                    w.focus();
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    alert(data.error);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    });
```

the .do executes the following:

```
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>> myMethod(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ParserConfigurationException
    {
        Map<String, String> respData = new HashMap<String, String>();
        try
        {
            String myXML = prepareMyXMLFile();   

            String result = sendMyXMLFile(myXML);

            respData.put("success", String.valueOf(true));
            respData.put("result", result);
            return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>>(respData, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            respData.put("success", String.valueOf(false));
            respData.put("error", String.valueOf(e));
            return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>>(respData, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
```

and finally sendMyXMLFile():

```
private String sendMyXML(String myXML)
{
    try
    {
        HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy()).build();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("myURL");
        List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("xml", myXML));

        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new 
        InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        StringBuffer responseResult = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
        {
            responseResult.append(line);
        }
        return responseResult.toString();
     }
     catch (IOException | TransformerException e)
     {
         //log error
     }
     return null;
 }
```

What do I need to do to use the response URL as the base URL in the other tab?
Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Hi, the best pratice when you post a question is to add all the code that can help to understand what is the current situation.

Comment: Code added to the question